# PHP display images dynamically in grid pattern

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I'm working with a tutorial about showing images dynamically on the page, it works fine but it shows them vertically and I would like them to be horizontal. I created a page with code to do that but I can't seem to figure out where to insert the code to get the images to show.
Thanks for any help.
**Vertical output** looks like this

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added ASC LIMIT 6");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="1000px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td width="1000px" align="center"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 0px solid;" src="images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br /> $' . $details . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">order</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

**`Grid Output`**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 15"); 
$i = 0;
// Establish the output variable
$dynamiclist = '<table width="1000px" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="10" align="center">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $details = $row["details"];
    $price = $row["price"];

    if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
        $dynamiclist .= '<tr><td>' . $product_name . '</br>' . $details . '</br>' . $price . '</td>';

    } else {

        $dynamiclist .= '<td>' . $product_name . '</td>';
    }
    $i++;
}
$dynamiclist .= '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Your not closing your row  </tr> until the end.  I think you need to close it on every loop.  If the counter "$i" is not equal to zero add a </tr> before the <tr>.  May need some additional tweeking on your exit code.  Also don't you want to add $details and $ price to items 2 and 3 on the list.  I would also double check your counter $i.  It may be simpler just to check if $i == 3

Comment: Hi Claus,Thanks for the suggestion. the code renders a 3 wide grid pattern in the browser but what I can't get it to do is add the images that go with the database like the vertical output does. I have tried it above the if statement  but that causes a syntax error with the if statement. I've tried it in the output variable but that causes undefined variables when I do that, so I'm out of suggestions of where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it figured out, Thanks for the help.**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 15"); 
$i = 0;
// Establish the output variable
$dynamiclist = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $details = $row["details"];
    $price = $row["price"];


    if ($i % 4 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
        $dynamiclist .= '<tr><td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>' . $product_name . '<br />
            ' . $details . '<br /> $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">order</a></td>';

    } else {

        $dynamiclist .= '<td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>' . $product_name . '<br />
            ' . $details . '<br /> $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">order</a></td>';
    }
    $i++;
}
$dynamiclist .= '</tr></table>';
?>
```